# Amazon EC2 Server upgrade to a better processor

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I am using this free tier Amazon ubuntu linux machine with with processor `'Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2676 v3 @ 2.40GHz'`. Can i increase its memory and processor, as i when i try to upgrade ubuntu, it gives me message 'not enough memory to upgrade'. Can it be made EC2 instance. If yes, what are the charges and options available.

Answer (score 1):

You can change your EC2 instance type at anytime.  The process is

- stop your EC2 instance type
- change the instance type
- start the EC2 instance

You can stop / start and change instance type in the console, CLI or using AWS' API.

Details are here https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ec2-instance-resize.html

There are a couple of compatibility rules to follow (you can not change instance type from 32bits CPU to 64bits CPU for example).  Rules are in the doc.

Comment: Can i us the same Ubuntu machine as EC2 instance as i dont want to do configurations again..??

Comment: It depends where is your current Ubuntu machine.  If it is on premises, importing is difficult.  If it is already an EC2 instance, you will not loose your configuration - everything will stay as is, because the operating system is on external volume (EBS) and these volumes will be re-attached to your new instance.

Answer (score 0):

In AWS you can change the CPU power of your instance by changing the instance [type](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/WindowsGuide/ec2-instance-resize.html),
depending on the instance type you choose, you will be able to increase or decrease the number of CPU cores of your CPU.

In order to compare between instance types available on [AWS view](https://aws.amazon.com/ec2/instance-types/).

To change your instance type follow the steps in [this guide](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/resize-instance/).